Tika unable to detect and parse the non-utf-8 encoded csv file containing non-ascii characters
I have a csv file saved as .csv format which contains non-ascii characters but Tika not able to detect the MimeType of the file and thus assigning the mimeType as application/octet-stream and during parsing, it is assigning an empty parser to it which is not generating any output. The csv file is not saved as utf-8 encoded format.
I tried to give mimeType of the file as text/plain to override. But it is not detecting the character encoding of the file correctly and after extraction, the generated output file is not the same as the input/original file. and also how to detect the correct encoding of the file?

If there are non-ascii characters in the file then what encoding is it?

The encoding is ANSI.

Please link to the file and tell what tika version you are using.
